# Why is my analog output limited to 2.7V?

Tags: analog

I have an MKR WIFI1000 (v2.0 [Arduino:XYZ]) with a "real" analog output pin (DAC0/A0/PIN15). According to the documentation, this is a 10 bit DAC, so I assume I can write `analogWrite(15, 1023)` to have an output of 3.3V on that pin.

However, I don't seem to get it higher than 2.7V, which is already reached well before a value of 256.

This is my code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define AN_OUTPUT 15

int counter = 0;

void setup()
{ 
  pinMode(AN_OUTPUT, OUTPUT);
}

void loop ()
{
  counter++;
  if (counter > 1023) {
    counter = 0;
  }

  analogWrite(AN_OUTPUT, counter);
  delayMicroseconds(1);
}
```

And this is the corresponding signal:

[image]

Comment: Did you explicitly set A0 to be an output? Read [this text about analog output on A0](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-basic-proto/adapting-sketches-to-m0#analogwrite-dac-on-a0-3008984-8)? Also remember the maximum value for a 10-bit DAC is not 1024 but 1023 (2^10-1).

Comment: Well, part of it is just that it's in 8-bit mode. And just to telegraph this for anyone that wants to get stupid about it: no that's not an answer. It doesn't explain why the graph output isn't closer to 3.3V or rather 250/255 * 3.3. If more code was in the question it be clear why it isn't a sawtooth shape even. Assuming there's a good reason for that, if this were my project just to sanity check I would measure the 3.3V pin and see that it really is 3.3V and not something closer to 255/250 * 2.7. Are you running from a low battery?

Comment: @StarCat I set it with `pinMode(DRIVE_PIN, OUTPUT)` and `DRIVE_PIN` is set to `15`.

Comment: @timemage I power the board from a USB port on my laptop.

Comment: Well, I have a samd21 board that isn't what you have but does use the arduino:arduino core for samd for its board definition. I tested with core version 1.8.13. I did analogWrite of 255 for the default 8-bit resolution to the DAC pin and it got within a few tens of mv of 3.3V. Just for the hell of it I did it on a PWM rather than DAC pin and it also gets pretty much right to the rail. If I use 250 it gives 3.22 V. My regulator is pretty much spot on 3.30. Not sure what to tell you other than to include more. All code and wiring information, all versions information, etc.

Comment: @timemage I updated my question

Comment: It's good that you added the code. I don't know what *"v2.0 [Arduino:XYZ]"* refers to.

Comment: @timemage that 's what I get for "Version" when I upload the program....

Comment: Well, it seems like you've answered it yourself, so I guess I'm just not going to worry about what it means. You didn't have the code in the question at the time I did my testing and I just didn't use `pinMode` / `OUTPUT` because there's no reason to. So, I'm curios to see if I can replicate the problem now that I know what it is using my own board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-basic-proto/adapting-sketches-to-m0) had the answer, you have to **remove** the `pinMode(PIN, OUTPUT)` line.